# Being Emotionally Moved by Yourself?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, adjectives

Is there a word that describes the state of mind of being moved by your own imagination or assumption?

For example, a boy thinks that he really loves a girl, and believes the girl will love him and idealizes his love because he has made a lot of efforts, but the truth is the girl doesn't like him at all.

Another example: ‘White Savior’-style volunteers who work in Africa to help local people and who think of theirselves as selfless angels but actually are of little help due to lack of ability.

Comment: I think "delusion" is the word you're looking for.

Comment: delusion +1 ... also vanity http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vanity  or hubris  ...  @Hansyvea, do you specifically mean the situation where someone is unrealistically proud of themselves, or more generally any strong feeling induced by a belief?

Comment: I mean that, like, you have some lofty thoughts: ‘I really have sacrificed a lot, the world shall become a ever brighter one,’ and you become so obsessed in your own feeling.

Comment: the boy could be said to be "in love with love", that is, "in love with the feelings associated with being 'in love' (infatuated).

Answer (score 1):

'How to use a word to describe a state of mind that you are moved by your ... assumption?

a **vainglorious** state of mind.

[vainglory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vainglorious)

Comment: Not exactly...if you continue to read the given examples, you may find it might not be vainglory...thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

[Presumptuous](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/presumptuous) - full of, characterized by, or showing presumption or readiness to presume in conduct or thought, as by saying or doing something without right or permission.

[Conceited](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conceited) - having or showing an excessively high opinion of oneself.

[Fanciful](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fanciful) - marked by fancy or unrestrained imagination rather than by reason and experience.

None of these seem quite perfect to me, but "fanciful" sounds like the best fit to my ears.